# Dialog interface hides animation in android

Tags: java, android

I want to remove a cardview from the activity after an alert confirmation.
If I delete cardview directly, the default sliding animation is shown, but with the DialogInterface i don't see the animation and cardview is not disappearing.
Below is the code

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this account?");
    builder1.setCancelable(true);
    builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    RelativeLayout rlMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMain);
                    CardView cv = (CardView) findViewById(id);
                    rlMain.removeView(cv);

                }
            });
    builder1.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();
```

Comment: Try move instructions from onClick to runOnUiThread. Every instruction which manipulate on User Interface should by inside.

Comment: @EliaszKubala thanks, looks like I messed up with the id of cardview, cardview was referring to wrong id, I changed the id and this code work fine now.

Comment: Good luck and have fun ;)